# Gsuite resources can't be shared with service account

Tags: google-calendar-api, google-workspace

I'm trying to fetch rooms (added from calendar.google.com) service account (created from https://console.cloud.google.com/iam-admin/serviceaccounts) in spring boot project.
I had one service account which I created 4-5 month ago, it was working and it is still working with the 3 specific rooms.
But if I add service account mail to other rooms, then these rooms are not returned in the project.
I did all the steps written here:
https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2ServiceAccount
https://support.google.com/a/answer/1034381?hl=en

Also, I tried removing the service account email from the room's "Share with specific people" list in Calendar, and then added it back (this helped sometimes in the past).

But the re-added room was also not returned in my project. 
I'm using this method from java to get the rooms.
https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/reference/calendarList/list
This look like a bug, so do you know how can I work around this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you shared the resource calendar with the Service Account through the UI, by adding the corresponding email in `Settings and sharing > Share with specific people`, the calendar might not have been added to the CalendarList.

In order to make sure that a calendar is added to the CalendarList of a Service Account, you should use the API and call [calendarList.insert](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/calendarList/insert).

#### Update:

There are currently several open issues in Issue Tracker regarding Service Accounts in Calendar. The situation you are experiencing is most probably related to that: check [this](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/141704931), [this](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/140746812) and [this](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/141903683), for example.

Meanwhile, I don't think using the API can be avoided. Maybe you could develop some kind of UI to make it less painful?

I hope this is of any help.

Comment: Thanks, I used calendarList.insert and inserted calendars were returned with calendarList.list .
But is there any reason why "Share with specific people" doesn't work? It was working before and my application was dependent on it, so is there other way to avoid calendarList.insert?

Comment: @giusha9 I updated my answer based on your comment.

Comment: @lamblichus thanks, this really seems issue with gsuite. I found the exact issue
https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/146362823
Just for information: when I inserted rooms from SQL script in my app, then all the other functions work(adding,removing,updating)
thank you for the help anyway