# List all calendars shared to a Service Account

Tags: google-calendar-api

I am working on an android application that needs to search for events in different calendars from a service account.
The calendars have been shared with the service account and I can access each one with "Calendar.get (" calendar.id) ", but I would like to be able to list all the calendars shared with this account without needing to know the specific ID of each one .

Investigating I found that by default calendars shared to a service account are not added directly to Calendarlist, so "Calendarlist.list ()" returns an empty object "[]".

Is there any method to list all shared calendars?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to list the calendars that have been shared with a service account (via [CalendarList: list](https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/reference/calendarList/list)), you should first insert the corresponding calendars individually via [CalendarList: insert](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/calendarList/insert).

This, of course, requires knowing the `id` for each of these calendars. There's no other way around it.

If your application workflow allows it, I'd recommend calling `CalendarList: insert` as part of the sharing process of each calendar.

#### Alternative: domain-wide delegation:

Also, if the point of using a service account is to avoid user interaction, you could grant it [domain-wide authority](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/service-account#delegatingauthority) and use it to impersonate a regular account instead (the account with which the calendars would be shared). This way, calendars would be added to `CalendarList` without having to call `CalendarList: insert`.

#### Related answer:

- [Gsuite resources can't be shared with service account](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59357149)

Comment: For domain-wide delegation is neccesary to configure google workspace?

Comment: @mxchxdx Yes, if you want to grant domain-wide authority you need to be a Workspace domain admin.